# td with colspan border broken in ie10 quirk mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, html-table

ie10 is not showing fine border over colspan. 
It is showing well on other browser, but not on IE 10.
I'll post my code below.

HTML CODE:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td colspan="4">3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td colspan="2">7</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td colspan="3">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS CODE:

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

border under 7 is gone. How can I show it?

here is example on jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/H4z7Q/

ADD: If some event occurs in ie10, border come back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table inline style stats. instead of `border-collapse:collapse;`

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
```

will count as same effect.
but will return and will chrice ur problem

Comment: `<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>` makes border thicker.. 1px->2px due to two cells have border either

Comment: you can use frame=box inline in table and increase the frame thickness to match up with the thickness of border. but that will increase the box-border thickness. That will almost kill your problem except you will have all the borders of 2px.Just so you know I just wanted to go through your problem the "old school" way.

Answer (score -1):

The markup violates the HTML table model, as you can see by checking it with http://validator.w3.org which says, referring to the first row: “Table column 6 established by element td has no cells beginning in it”.

So all bets are off. Modify the table structure so that it conforms, or try to achieve the desired layout using other tools than a layout table.